How do I correctly specify feerange of [slow,normal] on running lightling-cli close?
I close my lightning channels on Core Lightning with the following Bash script:
#!/usr/bin/bash

close_channel() {
echo -e "${ita}unilateraltimeout${end} in seconds?";read tmt
echo "Give the short channel id of the channel to be closed.";read scid
echo "Destination?";read dst
#lightning-cli -k close id="${scid}" unilateraltimeout="$tmt" destination="$dst" feerange="[slow, normal]"
lightning-cli -k close id="${scid}" unilateraltimeout="$tmt" destination="$dst" feerange="[2000,7000]"
}

close_channel

When feerange="[2000,7000]" is given, the command properly initiates channel's closing. But when given feerange="[slow,normal]" or feerange="[slow, normal]" I get the error message about the parameters being malformed:
lightning-cli: Some parameters are malformed, cannot create a valid JSON-RPC request: { "jsonrpc" : "2.0", "method" : "close", "id" : "cli:close#xxxxxx", "params" :{ "id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "unilateraltimeout" : 30000, "destination" : "bc1qxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "feerange" : [slow,normal]} }

For the sake if privacy I replaced identuifying info with x.
